# How do I extract the value of a label on gridview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Does anyone know how I can extract the value of the label below?

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Event Dates">
              <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("eventDates","{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
             </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

I am querying the database and would like to use the label value on the WHERE clause.

For instance,

This isn't working:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from mytable where username= @username and eventDate = @edate", myconn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@edate", Label4.Text)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the row first.  Then from the row find the control

```
var label4 = (Label)row.FindControl("Label4");
var labelText = label4.text;
```

Comment: please forgive me if I ask some dum questions but where should I put this code?

Is it in page_load() event?

I tried testing it in page_Load() event but I am getting an error that
`'System.Data.SqlClient.Row' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'`

Comment: That depends on when you want this code to be executed.  Do you want it to fire when the page loads?  When the grid binds?

Comment: it really doesn't matter. I just want to fix the error.

Although, I will be using it in a function so I can pass the value of that date label to my query.